# Assigning value of JS code to DIV

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a variable in JS code to be displayed within a DIV within a table.  I've cut the code down for simplicity just trying to get this working properly.

Firebug is reporting:

```
document.getElementById("valuelabel") is null
```

Here is the code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Value:
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="valuelabel"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var mktValue = "12000";
  document.getElementById("valuelabel").value = mktValue;
</script>
```

The mktValue will be a dynamically assigned numeric value; a textbox entry from another form.  I just put "12000" in for testing purposes.

Within Firebug, it's shows the following for the dynamically assigned value.

```
var mktValue = '120700';
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Divs don't have a "value", they do however have "innerHTML"

```
document.getElementById("valuelabel").innerHTML = mktValue;
```

Comment: I keep getting a "document.getElementById("valuelabel") is null" error within Firebug.  I'm not sure what is going on.  I think it may have something to do with the full dotnetnuke module I'm trying to use the code within and not the actual JavaScript code itself.

Comment: @user1424532 Then try running that code you posted on a clean HTML page. If it works, then you're right.

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements don't have a `value` (only form fields do). You can set the `div`'s content via `textContent` (just text) or via `innerHTML` (HTML):

```js
document.getElementById("target1").textContent = "This is normal text, <and> aren't special here.";
document.getElementById("target2").innerHTML = "This is HTML text, so <strong>tags</strong> are rendered as elements.";
```

```html
<div id="target1"></div>
<div id="target2"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery to insert value into the specific id by using

`$("#valuelabel").html(mktValue)`